# Allah will really grant desires in Jannah?

Tags: jannah

What if I asked Allah to change my race or color to the desired race or nationality I want could He do it?

What about those that desire to change their sex or gender, will this desire be possible to be granted by Allah?

I hear my friends say that Allah can never change my ethnicity, nationality, race. They say that God will not do something like this because it is impossible. They believe God will not change my race if I ask him, are they right? Are they more correct? I told them that God grants all our desires and they still said no. They are Christians, but I am non-denominational, I believe in Allah and listen to Muslim/Islamic teachings. I want to be like Anne Morrow Lindbergh. I am Indian and want to be white in Jannah and I want to look like Anne Morrow Lindbergh. **I heard Muslims say in Jannah, you will look like how you want to look.** My friends still say no. I wanted to tell them that we would get whatever we want in Jannah.

So can God change my appearance and race and ethnicity to what I prefer in Jannah?

I was tortured by my Dunya family can I also ask to have a new family in Jannah? I made dua but they are still abusive.

Comment: Why is everyone asking this?

Answer (score 0):

Our knowledge on Jannah is limited to what has been revealed. We find several descriptions in the Holy Quran but still we must assume that these are only images God has given us, e.g.

al-Baqarah 2:25-26

> And give good news to those who believe and do righteous deeds; that
> they will have gardens beneath which rivers flow. Whenever they are
> provided with fruit therefrom as sustenance, they will say, “This is
> what we were provided with before,” and they will be given the like of
> it. And they will have pure spouses therein, and they will abide
> therein forever.
>
> God does not shy away from making a parable of a gnat, or something
> above it. As for those who believe, they know that it is the Truth
> from their Lord. But as for those who disbelieve, they say, “What did
> God intend by this

Maryam 19:61-62

> The Gardens of Eden, promised by the Most Merciful to His servants in
> the Unseen. His promise will certainly come true. They will hear
> no nonsense therein, but only peace. And they will have their
> provision therein, morning and evening.

Ya-Sin 36:55-58

> The inhabitants of Paradise, on that Day, will be happily busy. They
> and their spouses, in shades, reclining on couches. They will have
> therein fruits. They will have whatever they call for. Peace — a
> saying from a Most Merciful Lord.

You will have what you call for. But will you still call for the same?

Will you want to change your etnicity, your race, your appearance when ethnic conflicts are settled and there is no more nationalism or racism and all appear in the beauty of their purged heart?

We do not know what Jannah will be but we can imagine a lot. And this imagination is healthy - it leads us to understand what is really desirable, to dream of an ideal world. It will also help us to understand how we would like our world here and now to be, to change here what we can change here, and to support with patiance what we cannot change, hoping on Jannah to come true for us.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, if you manage to enter Jannah, you will not have those ideas, but if you assume you do, there will be no nationality. You will be at the maximum beauty one can be, and all people faces will be between the glowing of the moon or the stars, so you will not see anyone more beautiful than you. Why would you be less beautiful (like Anne) then.

**More important**

First you need to enter Jannah to be able to ask.
To enter Jannah you must be one of those Allah accepted them.
To be accepted you need to be a believer, follow the way of the prophet Mohammad PBUH and you need to come to Allah with a sound heart:

> Only those who come before Allah with a pure heart ˹will be saved
> [26:89](https://quran.com/26:89?font=v1&translations=20%2C131)

Believing is not just saying Allah is there and he created us and we will return to him, but to believe in all his attributes.When you beleive he is the wise, that means you trust and accept his choices for you, you would not want to change what he chose for you.

What you will have or be at of state in Jannah is beyond your immagination, that makes anything you wish for now very low comparing to what Allah prepared for you.

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Allah said, "I have prepared for My Pious slaves things which have never been seen by an eye, or heard by an ear, or imagined by a human being." If you wish, you can recite this Verse from the Holy Qur'an:--"No soul knows what is kept hidden for them, of joy as a reward for what they used to do." (32.17)
> [Narrated Abu Huraira](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3244)

Also the prophet told us, no one In Jannah will have anything more to ask, and that when Allah give them even more:

> He will ask them: 'Are you pleased?' They will reply: 'Why should we not be pleased, O Rubb, when You have given us what You have not given to any of Your creatures
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1894)

**Correction** The proper way when talk about Allah is to say "Will Allah do?", with Allah one does not say "*Can Allah do?*" because Allah ability is limitless.